# SmsManager how to make it try to resend if the sending has failed?

Tags: android, sms, send

According to [SMS Delivery Report in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589642/sms-delivery-report-in-android) in answer 2 i have managed to get it working but what i want to do is if the SMS sending has failed is there a way to make Android try and resend the SMS again once the Mobile Service is available again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing your own SMS application, it is your responsibility to implement a outgoing folder (for lack of better terminology).

I suggest that you insert the SMS into this folder (or database) and use a task with a timer which attempts to send your messages if network connection is available or waits for the network connection to become available.